# What are the reasons behind the index going higher and higher every year?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-valuation

The following is the chart for NASDAQ from the year 1981 to 2021. The chart shows:

- Index went so higher in 2000 to 5000 points
- Bottomed in 2002 to 1250
- Went up and bottomed in 2008 to 1400
- The Market went so higher from 1400 in 2008 to 15000 recently

My questions are:

- The last 12 years is called a **bull market**. I know only that the bull market goes up and bear market goes down. Are there any technical reasons why a market is called **bull** or **bear**? As an example do they correlate to GDP?
- What are the reasons the index is so high with 1000% growth now compared to 12 years ago? Is one reason, the people have bought more stocks and invested 1000% now compared to the year 2010?
- Do someone in the stock market bump up the index value to some high level every year considering some technical factors? If so, what are they?
- During the pandemic last year, all indexes dropped 15% every other weeks or so. At that time, the stock market halt the trades. Then the market goes up and stabilizes after a while. Does that mean, the stock market does not allow to drop beyond a certain level, so the NASDAQ can never go lower than 6890 which happened on March 20 last year?
- Is it ever possible that the index can go back to 1400 level like in 2008? For example, the growth stalls for the next 5 years due to interest rate goes higher?

**Logarithmic Chart:**

[image]

**Linear Chart:**

[image]

Comment: Consider uploading a semi-log chart instead.

Comment: I added a logarithmatic chart.

Comment: This is too many questions in one

Comment: The situation since 2008 is government supported financial markets.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the reasons the index is so high with 1000% growth now compared to 12 years ago? Is one reason, the people have bought more
> stocks and invested 1000% now compared to the year 2010?

One reason for the growth was that 2010 was at/near the bottom for stock prices. The index went up because stock prices went up. They went up because money flowed into the stock market.

> Do someone in the stock market bump up the index value to some high level every year considering some technical factors? If so, what
> are they?

The index is just a number based on the prices of the dozens, hundreds, or thousands of companies that are a part of the index. Those prices are put through a formula and the answer is the current value of the index. Nobody is bumping the index. It moves every seconds that the market is open.

> During the pandemic last year, all indexes dropped 15% every other
> weeks or so. At that time, the stock market halt the trades. Then the
> market goes up and stabilizes after a while. Does that mean, the stock
> market does not allow to drop beyond a certain level, so the NASDAQ
> can never go lower than 6890 which happened on March 20 last year?

Each market has a set of rules regarding when they pause trading, and for how long. They are looking for quick drops where the the belief that general fear and panic would cause prices to spiral out of control. The pause is designed to allow everybody to breath and calm down. There isn't a set number it is a percent drop over a short period of time.

The indexes dropped because most companies saw their stock price drop.

> Is it ever possible that the index can go back to 1400 level like in
> 2008? For example, the growth stalls for the next 5 years due to
> interest rate goes higher?

Yes prices could go backwards. Sometimes they do. It can take years to reach the bottom when a bubble bursts.

Comment: Touching on your last point about 'bubble burst'. If investors have poured money into the market in the last ten years, the money can't vanish quickly if the index drops and reaches a bottom. These investors have to take the money to invest somewhere like gold. They have to bring it back to the stock market again to make profits. Am I right that the market will go up again when that short bear market is over?

Comment: @wonderfulworld You are misunderstanding - when the total value a company's stock [or an 'index' of stocks] drops by $5M, it doesn't mean that $5M was 'withdrawn'; it means that the last transaction occurred at a new lower price. ie: the 'market' realized or believed that the old price was too high. When Enron's stock valuation dropped from $70B to $0 after the company went bankrupt, the old investors didn't take $70B and buy gold, they simply held shares that were no longer worth anything. If you buy a $1M ferrari and then crash it, you just lost $1M; it doesn't imply you bought 20 corollas.

Comment: Isn't one reason the stock price drops and thus the stock value of the company also drops due to the investors selling the stocks? If the sellers have made profit, isn't it equivalent to they have 'withdrawn' money?

Comment: The price can drop even if 99.9% of the shares aren't sold during the panic. In 2020 the entire market dropped 20-30% and I never sold a share.

Answer (score 1):

[Where Did "Bulls" and "Bears" Come From?](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/bull-bear-market-names/)

> ...the actual origins of these expressions are unclear. Here are two of the most frequent explanations given:

> The terms "bear" and "bull" are thought to derive from the way in which each animal attacks its opponents. That is, a bull will thrust its horns up into the air, while a bear will swipe down. These actions were then related metaphorically to the movement of a market. If the trend was up, it was considered a bull market. If the trend was down, it was a bear market.

> Historically, the middlemen in the sale of bearskins would sell skins they had yet to receive. As such, they would speculate on the future purchase price of these skins from the trappers, hoping they would drop. The trappers would profit from a spread—the difference between the cost price and the selling price. These middlemen became known as "bears," short for bearskin jobbers, and the term stuck for describing a downturn in the market. Conversely, because bears and bulls were widely considered to be opposites due to the once-popular blood sport of bull-and-bear fights, the term bull stands as the opposite of bears.

> **Literary Evidence for Bear**

> According to Merriam Webster, the term "bear" came first:

> "Etymologists point to a proverb warning that it is not wise 'to sell the bear's skin before one has caught the bear.' By the eighteenth century, the term bearskin was being used in the phrase 'to sell (or buy) the bearskin' and in the name 'bearskin jobber,' referring to one selling the bearskin."

> Over time the name "bearskin jobber" was shortened to just "bear," and the definition was expanded to include the financial markets, which used "bear" to describe a speculator selling stock. One of the earliest references of the term "bear" used to describe a marketplace transaction came in 1709 from Richard Steele, publisher of the British literary and society journal, The Tatler. In an essay, Steele defines a "bear" as an individual who places a real value on an imaginary object and thus is said to be "selling a bear."1

> This negative image of the bear continues in Daniel Defoe's "The Political History of the Devil" published in 1726. In the book, Defoe writes:

- "...every dissembler, every false friend, every secret cheat, every bear-skin jobber, has a cloven foot."